# How to increase the limit of redirects with axios

Tags: javascript, axios

Hey there I was trying to request using the `axios` library and this is what I have so far -

```js
axios.get("https://example.com").then(console.log)
```

but it throws an error everytime `Maximum number of redirects exceeded`

How do I fix it by increasing the redirect limit ?

Comment: it needs some context for that code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `maxRedirects` option in the request config by passing a second object argument, by default it is set to 21. You'll need to ensure that your redirects don't end up causing an infinite loop. You can find other config options in the axios [docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config):

```
axios.get("https://example.com", {maxRedirects: 21}).then(console.log);
```